# Mocking a http response in kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jvm, kotlin

Currently I am working on a hobby project with that I want to learn a bit about kotlin.
I implemented an object that makes HTTP get requests and returns the Json object from the response.
What I'm struggeling with is the mocking of the response or the http framework in my tests.

I think if the framework would provide a class, I could manage the mocking. But as it only provides functions like khttp.get(), I'm a bit confused how to mock that.

Can someone help me, please? :)
Thanks!

The HTTPClient Class:

```
package dao.http.HTTPClient
import khttp.get
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.net.URLDecoder

class HTTPClient {
  fun getClient(): HTTPClient {
    return this
  }

  fun httpRequestGET(url: String): JSONObject {
    val r = get(url)
    return r.jsonObject
  }
}
```

And the related test Class

```
import dao.http.HTTPClient
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.spyk
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is` as Is
import khttp.responses.GenericResponse

class HTTPClientTest  {

    @Test
    fun testHTTPRequestGET() {
        val http_get = spyk(khttp.get( "https://somepage.com/wp-json/tsapi/v1/user/ts/isregistered/12323"))
        val httpClient = HTTPClient()

        var expectedAnswer: JSONObject = JSONObject("""{"uid":"1","user":"user","is_registered":"true"}""")
        every { http_get } returns GenericResponse()

        var url = "https://somepage.com/wp-json/tsapi/v1/user/ts/isregistered/12323"

        var actualAnswer = httpClient.httpRequestGET(url)

        assertThat(actualAnswer.get("user"), Is(expectedAnswer.get("user")))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like this:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    mockkStatic("khttp.KHttp")
    verify { khttp.get(any()) }
    verify(exactly = 1) { khttp.get(url = "http://google.com") }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I'll have a look and approve the answer when I've got a free minute